# Shuffling a List Based On an Int List

Tags: list, haskell, shuffle

Given the code:

```
data Error a = Fail|Ok a
               deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

split :: Int -> [a] -> (Error ([a],[a]))
split 0 list = Ok ([], list)
split n list
    | n < 0 = Fail
    | n > length (list) = Fail
    | otherwise = Ok (take n list, drop n list)

interleave ::  [a] ->  [a] -> [a]
interleave list [] = list
interleave [] list = list
interleave (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys


shuffle :: [Int] -> [a] -> Error [a]
```

How I write the function `shuffle` which will take a list of Ints, and split another list based on those ints. Examples of the int list would be intList = [20,23,24,13] where shuffle will split a list after the 20th element, interleave, split after the 23rd element, interleave, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, what you want is basically the following:

Given a list `xs` and indices `[a1, a2, a3, ..]`, split `xs` at `a1`, interleave, split it at `a2` and interleave, and so on...

Now that leaves us with two functions:

```
step :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
step index xs = ??? -- something with split and interleave

shuffle :: [a]
shuffle [] xs = xs
shuffle (i:indices) xs = let newList = step i xs
                         in ??? -- something with recursion
```

Try to write the rest of these functions on yourself.

> `step` can easily be expressed as `let (x1, x2) = split index xs in interleave x1 x2`. Basically, the rest of `shuffle` can be written as `shuffle indices newList`.

Comment: But the `split` function returns an Error ([a],[a])

Comment: This is the part where you think about how to apply your constraints to the solution. It's the most fun in my opinion ;)

Comment: I couldn't really understand your solution, but I managed to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
shuffle [] xs = Ok (xs)
shuffle (x:xs) list = case (split x list) of
                           Fail        -> Fail
                           Ok (l1, l2) -> shuffle xs (interleave l1 l2)
```